# passing values between classes by sharedPreferences in Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, sharedpreferences

I want to save a value in login page that I can use afterwards in other fragments. For doing this I used sharedPreferences and could store the "username", and here is the code:

Login.java

```
btnl.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // get The User name and Password
        String userName=un.getText().toString();
        String password=pa.getText().toString();
        String PATIENTID="";

        // fetch the Password form database for respective user name
        String storedPassword=demoCRUD.getSingleEntry_Username(userName);

        // check if the Stored password matches with  Password entered by user
        if(password.equals(storedPassword)) {
            show("Welcome!");
            SharedPreferences userDetails = getContext().getSharedPreferences("userdetails", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            Editor edit = userDetails.edit();
            edit.clear();
            edit.putString("_user", userName.trim());
            edit.apply();
            Intent intentLogin=new Intent(getActivity(),Welcome.class);
            startActivity(intentLogin);
        }
        else {
            show("User Name or Password does not match");
        }
    }
});
```

In addition I could fetch the value again using sharedPreferences in other fragment using the following code:

EditPersonal.java

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ep_demoCRUD = new DemographicsCRUD(getActivity());
    SharedPreferences userDetails = getContext().getSharedPreferences("userdetails", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String puser = userDetails.getString("_user", "");
    show("puser = " + puser); *SHOWS ME IT HAS A STRING INSIDE
}
```

Also in "EditPersonal.java" I have this piece of code that call a method from different class:

```
protected Long doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
    return ep_demoCRUD.UpdateDemographics(ep_demoId,puser);
}
```

**The problem is that when onCreate method of "EditPersonal.java" run, "puser" has a value equal to the username from Login.java, but once "doInBachground" call the method "ep_demoCRUD.UpdateDemographics(ep_demoId,puser);" it pass null! 
I printed the Log and I understood puser=null. 
I can't understand what is the problem? why "null" is passed while it has already had the value ?**

p.s the method UpdateDemographics is defined as following:

```
public long UpdateDemographics(Demographics_to demoId,String us) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(DataBaseHelper.lastName, demoId.getD_lastName());
    values.put(DataBaseHelper.firstName, demoId.getD_firstName());
    values.put(DataBaseHelper.dateOfBirth, demoId.getD_dateOfBirth());

    Log.d("puser","=" +us); * NULL IS PRINTED IN LOG*

    long result = database.update(dbHelper.Demographics_Table,values,"username = ?" , new String[]{us});
    Log.d("Update Result:", "=" + result);
    db.close();
    return result;
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Use `edit.commit()` instead of `edit.apply();`

Comment: @Piyush Gupta, If this is on the main thread, its better to use edit.apply() instead of edit.commit(). But this doesn't effect the question.

Comment: @PiyushGupta sorry but as our friend mentioned it does not affect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you are using two variable with same name puser ,, one of them global and the other is Local ,, Just make sure if thats true or not ,, if not then show me the full code of class EditPersonal.java

Comment: oh thanks :) it was my bad , as you said I had 2 different declarations with same name . now the code works. but I used getString inside doInBackground.

Answer (score 1):

```
doInBackground(Void... arg0){}
```

You do not give the puser variable in the AsyncTask. Why not? is puser a global var?

try giving the puser var with the AsyncTask.

```
doInBackground(String... puser) {
 return ep_demoCRUD.UpdateDemographics(ep_demoId,puser);
}
```

can you post the whole AsyncTask and where **puser** is defined?

Comment: your answer is also right. yes before puser was global variable. but I edited it as I mentioned above. @dennis

Answer (score -1):

Why are you using `editor.clear()`? If you want to store, replace `editor.clear()` with `editor.commit()`;

Comment: Do not use terms such as `bcz`,'u' or any other slang.

Comment: doesn't matter. .clear() clears the sharedPrefs, but he does .apply() afterwards. So a value has been set.